# How to process the frame before display in VLC media library

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vlc, libvlc, subtitle

I'm using VLC library to create a simple media player, the program will display instructions above the video. These instructions are varying in position, size and color. I need to process the video frame before it's displayed to add my drawings. How can this be done? How can I have the libvlc show this large text when changing the volume up or down?

Comment: One thing you should know is that `libvlc` is as good as we would like it to be when trying to do frame-related stuff. You should try to use subtitles instead to achieve what you are trying to do. Concerning the changing volume, I think having a look at VLC callbacks can help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the problem is that I must have full control over the drawing the client asked for a moving text from down to up and from right to left or reverse, also to have bold words or with different colors so this seems impossible to be achieved by the subtitles, I've already looked at the VLC source code but it's so big, i wish to find someone experienced in VLC to tell me which module to search in? also i need a downloadable VLC API help.